# Relationship with former colleagues

Tags: colleagues, relationships, legal, invoices

Recently I have been receiving private messages from two former colleagues whom I worked closely with while was working as an intern at my previous workplace. The first guy was my supervisor, he wanted me to work on a project I was solely working on as an intern (now the project needs to go on the market but it had one issue of missing component), I initially accepted the request to work on it because I felt I didn't leave enough documentation on most of the components. After the first fix, I got another issue fix request but I turned it down and since then he don't connect with me on WhatsApp like before. ( I'm a bit worried but I think what I did what's right ).

Just today, I was contacted again by another colleague, this time he needs help on a project they are about work on.
When I was there, normally on my leisure time, I research on how to build applications on the company's APIs and one idea that came up was Invoicing. I started working on the idea and even started coding from the company assigned laptop ( It wasn't a crime as an intern and as long as the company didn't have such project, I was okay to work on it).
I did asked questions on how the existing system works and this colleague was always explaining things and at that time I had no intentions to leave the company so I was planning to discuss the idea with the CTO and unfortunately I couldn't have the chance before my internship ended and I left the company.
Now this friend said he need help on how I was implementing the invoicing idea 
as they have a new CTO and they want to implement something like that,
but I want to turn his request down because after my research I realize that the idea was bright and I have been working on it ( implementation and connecting with potential investors (local banks)).

I don't know if I'm doing is right or wrong regarding my relationship with them personally and legally is it okay continue with the implementation as my own product?

Comment: Are you getting paid for this work?  If not, why bother?

Comment: no I'm not getting paid, but these guys  job positions are on the red line.. apart from the individual relationship.. I'm not ready to work for their company even if they are paying me.

Comment: Their job positions being on the red line is not your problem.  Ultimately, they are the ones getting paid for your work and you are left with nothing.  And the fact that one stopped communicating after you turned down a request indicates there is no real relationship, they are just using you

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you asking if it's OK to associate with these people? Are you asking if it's OK to work on their product without being paid for that work? Are you asking if there's a conflict of interest regarding the work you've done for them and the work you're doing at your current employer? What is is that you're asking, exactly?

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm interested in working on the product as my own business product, my current employer is into a different thing and per the employee policy I'm okay to work on any thing once it's not on working hours and it doesn't conflict with it's business goals

Comment: @sf02 thanks, the company it self used me big time and as my days was ending as an intern I saw it clear that I'm needed not more than intern

Comment: Don't worry about it. Just tell them you're otherwise engaged, and can't help them. Then speed up your own development efforts, and beat them to market.

Comment: @AndreiROM, that's my plan, I already have about 70% development done

Comment: Perfect! You have nothing to worry about, then.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following this from an intellectual property perspective. You claim you were developing an invoicing solution against company APIs on a company laptop. Then you left the company. And now the company is contacting you to ask questions about that invoicing solution. But then you say in comments that they're "in to a different thing." It seems like the core issue here is whether or not your employer owns the IP you developed while you worked there, and it's really not clear to me if that's actually answerable.

Comment: @dwizum, I was an intern in a payment processing company, during my internship I worked on a mobile app (solo) under supervision, during that time on my free time, I did research on possible solutions that can be build on the company's API and I got an idea which I never discuss with anyone though few colleagues saw me working on the idea. Now I'm working for a different company and I still continue developing the idea but today a former colleague contacted to ask about how I was implementing the idea because they want to work on something like that.

Comment: @dwizum, Is it wrong to continue the development as I started it on that company's laptop ( by the rule, I'm okay to do so once the company is not having that on their project goals)

Comment: I think that's a question that is ultimately up to company policy or regulation. In some jurisdictions, it's common for companies to be able to claim ownership over any IP developed on their hardware, even if it's on your free time. In some cases, their reach may even extend to work you did on your own hardware, on your own time, simply because it had some minor degree of overlap with what you did or learned at work. In other cases, none of this applies. I don't think any of us can answer which is the case for you.

Comment: If you are truly interested in pursuing this as a business opportunity, you should probably get some legal advice from a lawyer before proceeding, versus asking us to give you advice.

Comment: @dwizum, that is great piece of advise...

Comment: In the meantime, you should just tell the other guy that you're super busy right now and that during your off-hours you don't want to talk about anything work-related. It's harsh, but you have to say something like that. Obviously, it also goes without saying that you should not volunteer anything about your own plans to any of your former co-workers.

Answer (score 4):

I would just go ahead and develop it myself. It's just an idea you had. Not something that was in any way company property.

Answer (score 2):

> I started working on the idea and even started coding from the company assigned laptop ( It wasn't a crime as an intern and as long as the company didn't have such project, I was okay to work on it).

As I understand, you worked on company laptop, on company time, and (likely, less relevant) on company money.

I would assume that the work you did belongs to the company, and if you use it outside, for whatever purpose, you might get into trouble.

It should be fine though to implement the same idea, but with different implementation, to avoid legal (intellectual property) troubles.

---

> legally is it okay continue with the implementation as my own product?

As I already mentioned, it is OK only if yo do a new different implementation, and only if you do not use intellectual property or other secrets belonging to the company.

---

> Relationship with former colleagues

If you like it, you might go out for some beer, or any other free-time activity. That is your only relationship with them now.

Answer (score 1):

As an "intern" did you have a contract? You mention that you did the work in your "free time." The company or legal jurisdiction may disagree that the time was "yours" if you had access to company property, assets and ideas. Also, since you did development on their property, you should be certain that you own the work that you did.

Consider this, if the company had not provided you with equipment and resources, you would probably not have been able to produce the work you now have. Thus, a contract is critical to delineating these, if one exists. Otherwise, the legal jurisdiction of your government may have rules that apply.

To be safe, you should re-develop your work to avoid these issues (I recognize how annoying that statement is, as I have done it myself). If you feel confident that you are in the clear on these issues, then there is the matter of your former colleagues.

When they ask for help, you should respond with, "I'm happy to help. What is the hourly rate for my consulting?" Your knowledge is clearly valuable, and you should get something in return. That may be awkward with a "friend" but if they try to imply you should do it for free as a "favor," remind them that your entire internship was for free. It helped you and them. Now, the internship is over and you would like compensation, just like the person asking you for help is receiving compensation for their work.

If they are your future competitors, you should "be nice" until they are actually your competitors. Be careful about your IP rights, since if this really makes you a lot of money, the people you formerly worked with will probably remember you, and legal issues will follow. The world is big, and yet it is small...